# Build Custom Ohai plugin for Windows Registry

Tags: key, registry, chef-infra, ohai-gem

I need to build a custom ohai plugin to read windows_registry keys and update the attributes while running the chef-client. I try to figure out on how to implement but left me more confused on how to use them?

Answer (score 1):

You can find our documentation on how to write a custom Ohai plugin at https://docs.chef.io/ohai_custom.html. Given the scope and scale of the registry, I would recommend limiting your plugin only checking certain keys, or you may run into either security issues (some registry data shouldn't be saved back up to the Chef Server) or scaling problems (if the node object gets too big, it can cause issues).